# Metro WSDL generation and nillable arrays

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I use Metro implementation of JAX-WS (v 2.2.5) and my WSDL is auto-generated on the server.

I have defined WS method:

```
@WebMethod
public String myMethod(@XmlElement(nillable=false) String[] array, @XmlElement(nillable=false) String field);
```

The problem is that 'nillable=false' doesn't work for arrays. Auto-generated WSDL is:

```
<xs:element name="array" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="field" type="xs:string"/>
```

I have found following fragment in Metro source code (class: AbstractWrapperBeanGenerator, method: processXmlElement):

```
boolean nillable = nav.isArray(type) || (elemAnn != null && elemAnn.nillable());
```

If I change this fragment to:

```
boolean nillable = (elemAnn != null && elemAnn.nillable());
```

everything works as supposed.

Do you know why it's made like this?

And do you have any idea how change this behaviour, but WITHOUT taking into consideration:

1. Changing the dafault metro source code
2. Using wrapper classes instead of arrays (for pure JAXB everything
   works fine)
3. Changing my implementation to contract first with manually corrected
   WSDL